# Macbook Pro doesn't recognize USB devices through hub

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, hardware

I have a [power delivery USB hub](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07L3W79R3) that I use to have a single cable I plug into my laptop to connect power, an HDMI monitor, and USB devices. It all works on other devices of mine, and mostly works for my Macbook Pro (i.e. PD and HDMI work), but the Macbook Pro doesn't recognize any devices beyond the USB hub, in particular mouse movements and keyboard strokes are not recognized by the laptop.

When I look at the System Report (Apple Logo -> About This Mac -> System Report...) in the USB section I can see what I believe to be the USB hub in question (when I unplug the cable and refresh it disappears), but nothing beyond the hub is listed. It lists the hub as a "USB3.1 Hub" when the Amazon listing for the device only claims 3.0. I do not know if this is related, but I currently don't know how I could take action based on that.

My laptop is up to date (macOS Catalina 10.15.3). I have tried plugging the USB devices "directly" into the mac (USB-A to USB-C converter) and they work fine. Plugging the hub into a different port on my Macbook does not fix the issue. As I mentioned, these peripherals work through the hub on every other device I've tried. I have tried restarting the Mac with the cable in and with the cable out. I have also tried unplugging the power delivery from the hub and plugging it back in just in case it's stateful. I also followed [Apple's guide for when USB devices don't work](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/if-a-usb-device-doesnt-work-mchlp1641/mac), but this did not resolve the issue.

How can I get this to work? What else should I do to troubleshoot?

Comment: I have the same problem with my Early 2015 MBP.  My life has been limited to two usb devices at a time for about a year.

Comment: This is the most comprehensive resource on the issue I've found: https://wls.wwco.com/blog/2016/03/20/usb-3-0-hub-stops-working-on-el-capitan/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've just stopped using my Macbook in this location, but if I decide to try again I'll follow that link.